# How can I share server resources (Ram/CPU) to my PC on LAN?

Tags: memory, cpu, windows-server-2012, resources, sharing

I have a Windows 2012 Server (Dell hardware) with 32GB RAM and good processing power (Xeon) that is more or less out of use now. 
I have a Win 10 laptop, that I do some graphics work and I would like to use my server resources for it.

Is there any way to achieve this? I don’t mean remote-desktop like solutions, because I can't install my applications on the server.

I want to literary share the RAM/CPU of my Server to my Laptop and benefit from its resources....  is there any solution for this out there ? or am I demanding for something 10 years ahead of our time?

Comment: You're talking about distributed computing, which has been around for 20 years. However, it is highly tailored for specific purposes. The biggest problem with what you're requesting is that much of the speed of a CPU and RAM is based on how quickly they can talk to each other and the other components of your computer. The network link between your computer and the server is like molasses compared to the speed of the internal communications inside your computer.

Comment: Essentially, you need apps that are built to do it [& have components on both local & remote machines]; it's not something you can just do on the fly. It's like ringing a taxi company to see if they can drive your car for you... first, they need the car...